# SSIS 2005 Process Task Timeout Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

Here is what I am trying to do.

1. I have a perl script that browses a website, fills out a form, and submits the form. This process takes about 1 minute to complete and will initiate an asynchronous process on the website to create a report and drop it to an FTP site.
2. After the form is submitted I would like to kill the process and report success.
3. After a period of time (hours) I will go to the FTP site to pick up the reports that were generated from the website.

To accomplish this I have a batch file which calls the perl script with a parameter for the report type to run. This works fine. When I call the batch script from the SSIS Process Task it works. However, I want the process task to terminate with success after 5 minutes so I set the timeout to 300 seconds but it still terminates with a failure.

Does anyone know how to make the process task report success so it will continue on to the next task in the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning the connecting line into a 'Completion' precedence constraint. I'm guessing the line will will be coloured green. Right-click on this, and change it to 'Completion'. It should turn blue.

The first task wille still terminate with a failure, however you will progress to the next no bother.

Let me know if this helps,

James